# How do I find the longest string in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-length

Something like `max(len(s1), len(s2))` will only return the maximum length. But if I actually want to find out which string is longer, and perhaps save it to another string, how is that done? `max(s1,s2)` seems to return the string with the larger value, but not necessarily the longest.

Note: this has to be done without lists or arrays.

Answer (score 40):

`max` takes a `key` function which causes `max` to take the max `key(val)` for each `val`, yet still return the `val`, to wit:

```
>>> max("foobar", "angstalot")
'foobar'
>>> max("foobar", "angstalot", key=len)
'angstalot'
```

Comment: >>> max("foobar", "foobak", key=len)
>>> 'foobar'

max might not be best solution here?

Answer (score 1):

```
def longest(a, b):
   if len(a) > len(b):
       return a
   return b
```

Comment: It works, but it's not idiomatic because precisely that functionality, in a more general and useful form, already exists among the builtins.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question to say "what is the one true way to do this?".

Comment: It's neither my downvote nor my question. But apart from that, a downvote does not mean "the answer doesn't address the letter of the question" but "the answer is not useful". And it arguably isn't, because it teaches unassuming readers to re-implement basic functionality instead of using the built in functions.

Comment: Fair enough. I agree that using the built-in is more 'pythonic' but disagree that a non-one-liner is not useful where a one-liner is available.

Comment: It's not about one liners (more often than not that leads to less readable code), but about re-implementing using four lines for something which is can be stated clearer, better and more general in *less* code.

Comment: No I completely get your point. And I agree. Just a bit grumpy about the downvote after a heavy week, I think. Time to close SO.

Comment: +1 to offset the downvote ... because strictly speaking this answers OP's question... Its fairly obvious from the +12 the other answer is the more pythonic answerr...

Comment: If TOOWTDI weren't hard to remember and ridiculous to pronounce, nobody would have these arguments. :)

Comment: @abarnert: I suspect Don't Re-invent The Wheel is closer to delnan's intent.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple conditional expression based on the length of each string is all that is needed:

```
longest = s1 if len(s1) > len(s2) else s2
```